# Sequence of maps not working - scala play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm having some problems when trying to map some different objects so that I can extract some fields from it.

I've the function in my controller like this:

```
def index = SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>

    transportService.allNonActive().map { transports =>

      val sourceEmailsListBuffer = ListBuffer[String]()
      val destinyEmailsListBuffer = ListBuffer[String]()
      val sortingCenterStockListBuffer = ListBuffer[SortingCenterStock]()
      val transportsListBuffer = ListBuffer[Transport]()

      transports.map { transport =>

        transportsListBuffer.append(transport)

        // gets SC of this transport
        sortingCenterStockService.retrieve(transport.idSCStock).map { sortingCenterStock =>
          Logger.debug(s"Entry on SCS")

          sortingCenterStockListBuffer.append(sortingCenterStock)
        }

        // gets email from source
        userDAO.find(transport.idSourceUser).map { option =>
          option.map { user =>
            user.email.map { email =>
              sourceEmailsListBuffer.append(email)
              Logger.debug(s"Entry on Source Email")
            }
          }
        }

        // gets email from destiny
        userDAO.find(transport.idDestinyUser).map { option =>
          option.map { user =>
            user.email.map { email =>
              destinyEmailsListBuffer.append(email)
              Logger.debug(s"Entry on Destiny Email")
            }
          }
        }
      }

      Logger.debug(s"Size of source emails: ${sourceEmailsListBuffer.size}")
      Logger.debug(s"Size of destiny emails: ${destinyEmailsListBuffer.size}")
      Logger.debug(s"Size of scs: ${sortingCenterStockListBuffer.size}")
      Logger.debug(s"Size of transp: ${transportsListBuffer.size}")

      Ok(views.html.transports.index(request.identity, sourceEmailsListBuffer.toList, destinyEmailsListBuffer.toList, sortingCenterStockListBuffer.toList, transportsListBuffer.toList))
    }
  }
```

When I load the page for the first time (with any minor change, i.e. I change the string I use to indicate what I'm debugging), it gets the info from the last map  `userDAO.find(transport.idDestinyUser).map`. When I  refresh the page, the list's size `destinyEmailsListBuffer` is 0 and it is  returned to the view before doing the map (at least I think so).

This is what I get after refreshing, after getting the correct output for the first time:

second load of the page
[image]

Thanks in advance, I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your general structure is wrong. For instance:

```
userDAO.find(transport.idDestinyUser).map { option =>
  option.map { user =>
    user.email.map { email =>
      destinyEmailsListBuffer.append(email)
      Logger.debug(s"Entry on Destiny Email")  // This returns Unit!
    }
  }
}
```

So you are using `map` operations and chaining those results to other functions, but instead if returning lists of items, you are incrementing an existing list that is never returned. Either return `destinyEmailsListBuffer` after logging or re-write to use `forEach` and to pick up the right values from somewhere.

Comment: Hi @daniel-l, I think I'm returning the `destinyEmailsListBuffer` when I call the view. I don't get why, but the other lists are not empty, and this (destinyEmails) is.

Comment: What I mean is that you have code that is equivalent to `user.email.map { email =>Unit`. Why would you ever map to Unit is beyond me. I would recommend you re-write your code using for-comprehensions to avoid all that nesting and make things easier to read. I would show you an example but I don't know the types of you objects and method return types.